# Is body temperature interval or ratio scale?

Tags: measurement

I understand that temperature is interval scale because it holds no true zero and can represent values below zero. But in case of body temperature it cannot go below a certain point and definitely not below zero. So in that case, will body temperature be a ratio scale?

Comment: How/where will you use this?

Comment: This question popped up in my mind while reading on levels of measurement. Everywhere temperature has been mentioned as an interval scale and the case of 0°C has been cited as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Any temperature, including body temperature, has a natural zero: $0$ K $(-273.15 °C)$. So, if you express it in Kelvins, it is ratio scaled. An object at 2000 K is twice as hot as an object at 1000 K.

Answer (score 0):

Distinguish the proper from the measurable: The human body temperature is *not* bounded. Imagine a body found buried under deep snow (brrrr!), its temperature is obviously below zero. It is a *measurable* body temperature, and the same applies for extremely high temperatures (although at some point it'll decompose so somewhere there is an upper bound).

A *proper* body temperature is bounded, whether you put the interval as 36-38°C for strictly proper or you set it to 34-42°C to include most conditions of illness (such as hypothermia).

For both cases (measurable and proper), as there is no real "true zero". We know a general lower bound on temperatures which is Kalvin's zero, −273.15 °C, but it is not feasible so this is not a ratio scale.